# Using UICollectionView and UICollectionViewCells for twitter like feed design

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm creating an app that has to display a stream of posts with images, text and other content with variable cell height. I am new to iOS and I can tell the UITableView is going to be a pain and using a UIWebView with HTML at the backend might be slow.

Is the UICollectionView (with one cell per row) a good approach or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UITableView is really what you should use.
It has a "heightForRowAtIndexPath" method that will fit your need.

UICollectionView is useless if you want only one cell per row.

Comment: What about properly designing the cell with multiple images, custom formatting etc